# My Java program keeps telling me that I can't put my else statement without an if, but I already have one

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String password, firstOption, firstNumber = "";
    int number, option;
    password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Password");

    // now starts code
    if (password.equals("HW1")) {
        firstOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select an option: \n0 = Quit \n1= Math Time");
        option = Integer.parseInt(firstOption);

        if (option == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Quit!", "Quitter!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        } else {
            firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 1-30:");
            number = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
            if (number <= 30 && number >= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number " + number + " to the second power is " + number,
                        "Math Time", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a number between 1-30",
                        "Idiot Alert!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            }
        }
     else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password", "Incorrect Password", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }
}
```

The problem is with the very last else statement, I want it to correspond to the if statement that says (password.equals ("HW1")

Basically I want it to check and see if the password is HW1, if so then run all the code in the if statement. If not, run the else statement

Comment: Check your syntax, your brackets, etc.

Comment: An `if` statement can have at most one `else`; it looks like your first `if` has two `else`s, which is not allowed.

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html And starting Java 7, check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: you didnt close your `if` statement `if (password.equals("HW1")) {` before writing `else{`

Answer (score 1):

Your else statement is out of scope - You have not put it in the correct place.

You should be looking at something along the lines of

```
if(password.equals("HW1") {
    //The password was correct
    ...
} else {
    //The password was incorrect
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password", "Incorrect Password", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the first `if` before you write the `else`.
Making the second `if` having double `else`...

Just try adding a `}` before the last `else`!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing curly bracket. The indentation tells you that.

Change:

```
        }
    }
 else {
```

To:

```
        }
    }
 } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, swap between **else** and the **parenthesis**

```
          else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Password", "Incorrect Password", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
```

take the else outside the parenthesis of if.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a bracket, try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String password, firstOption, firstNumber = "";
    int number, option;
    password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Password");

    // now starts code
    if (password.equals("HW1")) {
        firstOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please select an option: \n0 = Quit \n1= Math Time");
        option = Integer.parseInt(firstOption);

        if (option == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Quit!", "Quitter!", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        } else {
            firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 1-30:");
            number = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber);
            if (number <= 30 && number >= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number " + number + " to the second power is " + number,
                        "Math Time", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is not a number between 1-30",
                        "Idiot Alert!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            }
        }
    } else {  // Modified: Bracket added
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password", "Incorrect Password", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }
}
```